# What is the use of “s” in “ne s'ouvre pas”?

Tags: pronoms, verbes, verbes-pronominaux

Why do we use a *s'* in this sentence:

> *La fenêtre ne s'ouvre pas !*

Is it because of the two vowels or for the type of verb?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

« *Is it because of the two vowels?* »
Oui et non.

- Non car:

  Le verbe employé ici n'est pas le verbe « ouvrir » mais le verbe « s'ouvrir ». Contrairement à l'anglais où on dirait « *The window is not opening!* », le français utilise ici le « s' » pour désigner que le verbe *ouvrir* est appliqué au sujet *fenêtre*. Un français traduisant mot à mot la phrase « La fenêtre ne s'ouvre pas ! » en anglais dirait :

  > The window is not opening itself!

  (Ce qui est évidemment incorrect)

  Quand le verbe n'est pas appliqué au sujet mais au COD, le « s' » n'est pas utilisé :

  > Michel n'ouvre pas la boîte.
- Oui car:

  Au lieu d'utiliser le mot « se », on utilise effectivement le « s' » pour éviter la succession de deux voyelles. Par exemple, on dirait :

  > La fenêtre ne se ferme pas.

  Mais on dit bien :

  > Le français ne s'improvise pas.

Answer (score 0):

S'ouvrir would be contraction of se and ouvrir.

Verbs that have se (or s') in front are called reflexive verbs.

They are about what an object does (or in this case doesn't) do to itself.

So "La fenêtre ne s'ouvre pas !" means, "The window doesn't open *itself*.